# JavaScript React event gets weirdly fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a HTML list using React. All works well, but I get some weird behaviour with the click event I assign to the `<li>`-tag. Here are two codes of which one works, but not the other.

The difference between both codes is the way I assign the onClick-event to the `<li>`-tag.

Within the not working code I tell the `onMenuClick` function which `area` I am speaking of. When loading the page, I get this method fired three times.

Within the working code I do not provide any arguments for the `onMenuClick` function. Here though I am not able to know which `<li>`-tag fired the event. I need to know it though, because I want to react on it.

Why is the event firing three times in the not working code?

Not working code:

```
var React = require('react');

var Application = React.createClass({
  onMenuClick: function(area) {
    console.log('Application.onMenuClick(' + area + ')');
  },

  render: function () {
    var classWideThis = this;

    var areas = [
      { "id": 0, "name": "Bidirektional" },
      { "id": 1, "name": "Schleifen" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Events" }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ReactJS Prototyp</h1>
        <div className="menuWindow topAbstand">
          <ul className="menuUl">
            {areas.map(function(area) {
              return <li className="menuLi"
                         key={area.id}
                         onClick={classWideThis.onMenuClick(area.name)}>
                       {area.name}
                     </li>
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Application;
```

Good working code:

```
var React = require('react');

var Application = React.createClass({
  onMenuClick: function() {
    console.log('Application.onMenuClick()');
  },

  render: function () {
    var classWideThis = this;

    var areas = [
      { "id": 0, "name": "Bidirektional" },
      { "id": 1, "name": "Schleifen" },
      { "id": 2, "name": "Events" }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ReactJS Prototyp</h1>
        <div className="menuWindow topAbstand">
          <ul className="menuUl">
            {areas.map(function(area) {
              return <li className="menuLi"
                         key={area.id}
                         onClick={classWideThis.onMenuClick}>
                       {area.name}
                     </li>
            })}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Application;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onClick` prop expect function to be passed. You call `onMenuClick` function and pass it's result as the property in the first example. You can change `onMenuClick` function to return function which handles click event and use closure to remember passed parameter:

```
onMenuClick: function(area) {
    return function() {
        console.log('Application.onMenuClick(' + area + ')');
    };
},
```

and then pass it to `onClick`:

```js
onClick={classWideThis.onMenuClick(area.name)}
```

More advanced (but better looking) would be to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) original `onMenuClick` function to the correct context and prepend parameters to it:

```js
onClick={classWideThis.onMenuClick.bind(classWideThis, aera.name)}
```

Comment: When I do that, the function is returned properly, but when clicking I get `Application.onMenuClick([object Object])` within the browser's Web Console. Seems `area.name` is not transmitted properly into the `area` argument of `function(area)`. You know why?

Comment: try to debug a little. print the object to the console - `console.log(area)`. what can you see?

Comment: Ok, after your edit (putting the `area` argument from the inner function to the outer function) everything works fine with non-bind-onClick. The bind-onClick example does not work. What's the advantage of `onMenuClick.bind(...)`?

Comment: @Socrates use bind-onClick with your original `onMenuClick` implementation and it should work. It will create new function from `onMenuClick` and prepend `area.name` parameter to it so it is similar to creating that inner-outer function.